# Auth0 with nodejs for running user specific queries

Tags: node.js, auth0, express-jwt

I am using auth0 for authenticating users, so I don't have to manage the user modal since auth0 already keeps that db
Can anybody guide on steps I need to take if I want to show data associated with the individual users when they sign in. I am using React as a frontend and Nodejs as a backend for my api's. Do I need to create user model in my node app & associate their id's to their individual records so that I can query the data per user id or is their any other way.

On React's side I simply have the authentication id_token as an header while making an api get/post request.

On the node side the basic Auth0 documentation describes how I authenticate my api :

```
var authenticate = jwt({
  secret: new Buffer(process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET, 'base64'),
  audience: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID
});
```

But this basically just authenticates it, how do I retrieve user specific data from api.
Also how to take it one step forward and enable multi-tenancy , is their any related documentation that provides a guide to breeze through the basic process.

Answer (score 1):

First request the e-mail using scope when you sign in

```
auth.signin({ authParams: {
   scope: 'email' // Specify the scopes you want to retrieve
}}
```

then you will have the email in `req.user.email`

https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt has more info on multi-tenancy

Comment: thanks for the comment , I was actually already getting the profile and token info back and wanted to know if I should still create user model in my backend for querying user specific results. Their support team suggested the same i.e creating a user data model in the db